# The difference between "each", "both", either

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs

The issue is confusing to me. That's what I heard from natives.

> 1 The house has a door at either end.
>
> 2 The house has a door at both ends.

Some say that 1 and 2 are correct and mean that there are two doors, one door at each end.

Others say that 1 doesn't mean that there are two doors. It means that there is only one door at either end.

Others say that 2 is incorrect because it's impossible to have one door at both ends. Probably, they meant it that way if we use "one door" instead of "a door". Would this make a difference?

> 3 The house has ONE door at both ends.

Do 2 and 3 mean the same or not?

Others say that the best is this:

> 4 The house has a door at each end.

What are your ideas, comments on the issues?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/either), "Either as a determiner before a singular countable noun can mean ‘both’". With this meaning, however, the criticism of the second sentence now applies to the first sentence.

The criticism about the second sentence is valid: you can't have **a door** that is in two places. Sentence 3 does not solve the problem, because you still only have one door. The corrected version would be:

> 2a. The house has doors at both ends

This is now grammatically correct because there are multiple doors, so they can be in two places, but it is ambiguous: there could be multiple doors at each end.

The fourth sentence is grammatically correct and unambiguous. **each** states that we are talking about the ends individually, so it is clear that we have exaclty one door at one end and exactly one door at the other end.

> 4. The house has a door at each end